# Which one should be to cross validated?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, validation

I felt a little bit puzzled about cross-validation.  CV is a method to find the best parameter to check the generalization ability of the classifier in the classification problem.

1. I am really not sure whether I should apply cross-validation on the training set or on the entire dataset? I prefer on the training set because if you apply it to the entire set, it will lead to overfitting again.
2. Next question is: what is the correct step to use cross-validation in the classification problem. My view is (1)separate the data set as training set and testing set;(2)apply CV to the training set to get the best parameter; (3)use the best parameter to train a model;(4)use this model to test the testing set.

Am I correct?

Comment: I have found a slide about SVM and libSVM in Python from Chaoyang University of Technology, which makes me more clear on this question. You can also check it from [http://web.csie.cyut.edu.tw/~shwu/PR_slide/SVM.pdf](http://web.csie.cyut.edu.tw/~shwu/PR_slide/SVM.pdf) THX~

Answer (score 0):

CV as a method to find the best hyperparameter should be done on the training set, as you indicated.

CV as a method of evaluating a modeling process should be done on the whole set, however.